# Sci-Fi story where Mars is ruled by dogs?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

This was a young adult book. It was old, probably from the 50's or 60's. And the young male protagonist was transported to Mars where it was ruled by dogs. I think he had a dog of his own that went with him.

Comment: Looks to be it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Herbert's Space Trip by Hazel Hutchins Wilson, possibly? 1965.

A humorous tale of interplanetary canine hijinks, in which resourceful Herbert foils a plot and saves the day after landing on the "dog-gonedest planet this side of Mars."

[http://www.amazon.com/Herberts-space-Hazel-Hutchins-Wilson/dp/B0007DX75A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007DX75A)